Why is generated html font size different than native font size
I have an html page, where I autogenerate a paragraph within a  segment, but the generated paragraph seems to have a different font size when viewed on a cell phone's browser.  I'm wondering what would cause this.   In the below example, the some paragraph text (small) text is about half the size of the this is different size...(big) text that is generated after you press the button


function update() {
    var div = document.getElementById("output")
    div.innerHTML = "this is different size... (big)";
}
p {font-size: 14px;}
<h1>Heading1(small)</h1>
<p>some paragraph text (small)</p>
<p><button onclick="update()">Filter</button></p>

<div id="output"></div>




Your generated <div> is not inside a <p>.  You'll get whatever the default <div> size is.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML has examples. You can either update your CSS to p, #output {font-size: 14px;}, or you can update your JS to output HTML inside of your div like div.innerHTML = "<p>this is different size... (big)</p>";.

I had indeed forgotten the <p> in the above example, and adding it in there fixes the example.  I still seem to be having an issue with the original though...   I literally have the html (as seen by 'inspect' from chrome): <p>extra1<\p> <div id="extra"> <p>"Note:"<\p> <p><\p> <\div>, where the second paragraph is being displayed as a different size than the original (and only on some smart phones).   I will create a new question as this seems to have diverged from what I originally asked
